# how many type of index in oracle and uses of hash index in oracle

Tags: oracle, hash, indexing

How many types of indexing are in Oracle, and what is a HASH INDEX and how does it compare to other indexes ?

Comment: Are you referring to the Oracle database?  Or to the TimesTen database owned by Oracle Corporation?  The Oracle database has nothing referred to as a "hash index".  The TimesTen database owned by Oracle Corporation has something called a "hash index".  The Oracle database has something called a "hash cluster".  Are you referring to one of those things?  Or to something else?

Comment: yes, i'm referring Oracle database's hash index.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hash index" in the Oracle database.  Did you read an article somewhere that used the term?  Could you link to that article?  Perhaps the author was referring to a different database product (MySQL and TimesTen, both databases owned by Oracle Corporation, have something called a "hash index").  Perhaps the author was misusing a term and was actually referring to a "hash cluster"

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different indices, see here for a discussion: http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_9i_indexing.htm

Although not supported in Oracle DB, in general Hash indices are best for equality conditions (like WHERE X = 23 ), and B-TREE indices (these are directly supported in Oracle DB) are best for inequality conditions ( like WHERE X < 16 ).

Comment: if you express the range of values with inequality conditions, such as `x > 3 and x < 10` then B-Trees are better suited for this. Hash indices are best suited for columns which you use for single value exact equality conditions, like primary keys.

Comment: What do you believe a "hash index" is?  The term does not appear in the article you linked to and there is no such thing as a "hash index" in Oracle.  Also a b-tree index is perfectly suitable to a range scan for inequality and range conditions

Comment: You can see hash indices vs b-tree just as I explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/index-btree-hash.html Actually this description is not directly related with Oracle DB, but the concept is as explained here.

Comment: That is a link to the MySQL 5.5 documentation (another product owned by Oracle the corporation).  It says nothing about Oracle the database which is the product the Burleson article is discussing.

Comment: I did, yes.  Oracle the database has no such thing as a hash index.  I'm not sure how it is helpful to discuss how hash indexes work in MySQL since there is no feature by that name in Oracle.  I guess it's helpful if someone wanted to know about features Oracle might implement some time in the future in some future release of the database...

Comment: OK, instead of wasting our energy here, I will update my answer in a minute. Check and give feedback please.